# JS access to python variables via flask {{ variable }} format not working

Tags: javascript, python, flask

python:

```py
import json
posts = [
{'author':'JL Rowling','title':'Harry Potter'},
{'author':'JRR Tolkien','title':'Lord of the Rings'},
]
encoded_posts = json.dumps(posts)
```

javascript:

```
let obj = {{ encoded_posts }};
```

JS error logged in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'
```

Here are the page according to the CONSOLE. It seems to be losing(?) the `{{encoded_posts}}`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

      <title>Flask Blog - About</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>About page!</h1>
    <script>
      let text = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
      text.addEventListener('click',function(){
        text.style.color = 'red';
      });

      let obj = ;
      let jsonPosts = JSON.parse();
      console.log(jsonPosts);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What's happening?

Comment: You have a typo in your script tag. `let obj = ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing:

```
let obj = JSON.parse('{{ encoded_posts }}');
```